# Convert datetime to mysql format on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i´m trying to convert a date to mysql format date but is not working.

```
@complain.date = Date.today.to_s(:db)
```

Also, i want to save it as datetime format.
Any suggests??

Comment: Aren't you using date fields when you create your migrations, in which case rails will do it for you.

Comment: Time.now.to_s(:db) or     Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to convert manually; just do:

```
@complain.date = Date.today
```

Comment: Remember that this only returns the Date. If you have a column of DATETIME type, you should use **Time.now.to_s(:db)**

Comment: the `:db` is no joke!